# C# PropertyGrid - Check if a value is currently beeing edited

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Is there a simple way to find out if a property grid is currently being edited by the user?

My usecase is the following:
I update the grid data every second. If the user is editing a value, all inputs get lost when my update is called. So what I want to do is only update if the user is not editing something.

Comment: Not available.  Provide a "Update enabled" checkbox or just don't use PG.

Comment: That would....suck. No chance to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any official way. However the following piece of code can detect when a grid entry is opened using the builtin text box editor, or the dropdown editor. It does not detect when an entry is opened using the small '...' edit button.

```
public static bool IsInEditMode(PropertyGrid grid)
{
    if (grid == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("grid");

    Control gridView = (Control)grid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(grid);
    Control edit = (Control)gridView.GetType().GetField("edit", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(gridView);
    Control dropDownHolder = (Control)gridView.GetType().GetField("dropDownHolder", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(gridView);

    return ((edit != null) && (edit.Visible & edit.Focused)) || ((dropDownHolder != null) && (dropDownHolder.Visible));
}
```

Of course, since it's based on the grid internal structure, it may change in the future, so, use at your own risk.