# Detect an open DropDown box in a PropertyGrid in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, propertygrid

**Situation:**
I have a window with an OpenGL scene rendered inside. Next to the OpenGL scene, I have a PropertyGrid of the selected 3D object in the scene.

Objects in the scene can be changed in other ways than just editing the properties (e.g. some objects are manipulated with a running script which moves / scales / colors / ... objects in the scene). To show a live feed of the object's values in the PropertyGrid, the grid gets refreshed each frame, like so:

```
void OnFrame()
{
    myPropertyGrid.Refresh();
}
```

**Problem:** Because of this refresh each frame, I can't open any dropdown box in the PropertyGrid (an open dropdown box gets closed immediately on a PropertyGrid refresh).

**Question:** Is there some way to detect that a dropdown is open (e.g. a property to check or event to subscribe to), and prevent refreshing while this is the case?

```
void OnFrame()
{
    if ( !PropertyGridInEditMode() )   // <-- What should this function check?
        myPropertyGrid.Refresh();
}
```

*Note: Apparently, a simple check on* `myPropertyGrid.ContainsFocus` *works fine when simply* typing *in a PropertyGridItem value field, but it fails to detect if a* dropdown *is open (I assume that's because the dropdown form is called with* `IWindowsFormEditorService` *and thus the dropdown is a separate form that's not a child of the PropertyGrid).*

Comment: It's answered in a previous post by Simon Mourier.. check it out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553423/c-sharp-propertygrid-check-if-a-value-is-currently-beeing-edited

Comment: Considering the specific part of detecting the drop down was already answer, perhaps a different approach may be useful?      If the object the property grid was bound to implements INotifyPropertyChaned, the fields should update automatically without causing the drop down to disappear.